# How to leverage Custom Styles & Markup Styles in the SharePoint 2010 CEWP (100% JavaScript Solution)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, cewp

In short, with a RichHtmlField we can customize which Styles & Markup Styles appear in the drop down lists on the Ribbon.  Using an OOTB Content Editor Web Part we cannot.

After interrogating / contrasting the RichHtmlField vs. CEWP (HTML/JavaScript emitted) I was indeed able to find a JavaScript solution.

While the RichHtmlField emits a Page Script to initialize the field control, the CEWP emits no such initialization script.  Moreover, the RichHtmlField emits a significantly greater number of HTML Attributes than the CEWP does, and two of those attributes are **PrefixStyleSheet** and **StyleSheet**.

**PrefixStyleSheet** identifies the style sheet prefix being used in the drop down menu.
**StyleSheet** is a server relative url to the branded css file.

So, with all these things being true, we should be able to initialize a CEWP with a branded stylesheet using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {

 // window.setTimeout(function() {

 $("div[RteRedirect]").each(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("RteRedirect"),
        editSettings = $("#" + id);

    if(editSettings.length > 0 && editSettings[0].PrefixStyleSheet != 'yourcustom-rte') {
       editSettings[0]['PrefixStyleSheet'] = 'yourcustom-rte';
       editSettings[0]['StyleSheet'] = '\u002fStyle Library\u002fen-US\u002fThemable\u002fCore Styles\u002f<somecustomstylesheet>.css';
       RTE.Canvas.fixRegion(id, false);
    }

 });

// }, 2000);

}, "sp.ribbon.js");

</script>
```

I hope this helps someone.  This code could go a lot of different directions.  I'm merely presenting the fundamentals.  If you add this to a master page inside an EditModePanel it will work cross site.

There is a timer in there as depending on the order of script loading something may mess with what you've done after you've done it.  Let me know if this works / doesn't work for you.

Would be cool to keep a running tally of solutions to this problem somewhere.

Cheers,

M

Answer (score 2):

believe it or not 4 years late this post was helpfull !

To make it work I had to change this :

```
 $("td[RteRedirect]").each(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("RteRedirect"); 
        editSettings = $("#" + id);
```

Thank you